SSL certification error while calling huggingface inference APIs via Langgraph & langchain
I am using Huggingface inference APIs for a basic GenAI applciation using Llama 3.2 & mistral. While calling the APIs i am getting the below error:
(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api-inference.huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /models/mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.3/v1/chat/completions (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '\[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED\] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (\_ssl.c:1000)')))"), '(Request ID: b4e71615-6cbc-4e46-9315-7403f74e398d)')

The same error persists for Llama 3.2 model also.
The relevant code snippet is as below:
@staticmethod
def retLLMModel():
    llm = HuggingFaceEndpoint(
        repo_id="mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2",
        # repo_id="codellama/CodeLlama-34b-Instruct-hf",
        max_new_tokens=1500,
        top_k=10,
        top_p=0.95,
        typical_p=0.95,
        temperature=0.01,
        repetition_penalty=1.03,
        huggingfacehub_api_token=os.getenv("HUGGING_FACE_KEY")
        )
    return llm

def retAgentExecutor(self,template,tools_list,llm):
    base_prompt=self.cqa_obj.get_hub()
    react_prompt = base_prompt.partial(instructions = template)
    agent  =create_react_agent(llm=llm,tools=tools_list,prompt=react_prompt)
        agent_executor=AgentExecutor(agent=agent,tools=tools_list,verbose=False,max_iterations=10,return_intermediate_steps=True,handle_parsing_errors=True)
        return agent_executor

def executing_function_name(state: GraphState):
    ## giving executing function relevant code part

    llm = Utils.retLLMModel()
    try:
        
        template = prompts_custom.SeqChainPrompt.get_react_user_query_template()
        template = template.format(user = messages_[0][1],columns=columns,dataframe_path=dataframe_path,python_tool=python_tool)
        agent_executor = utils_obj.retAgentExecutor(template,tools_list,llm) 
        result = agent_executor.invoke(input={"input":messages_[0][1]})

        code = result['output'].strip("```</s>")
        if len(code.split("```"))>1:
            code = code.split("```")[1].replace("python","")

        print("result  = ", result)

         
      
    except Exception as e:
        error.append(f"yes : {e}" )
        #print(e)
        #print("error_code 1 = ", error)
        return {"generation":" ",
                "error":error}

I tried updating the requests library & also set the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE environment variable correctly and confirmed that certifi is installed. What can i do to resolve this ?
